# Preposition "to" in "...accept the consequences of to..."

Tags: prepositions

I'm doing a test from a Cambridge book. There's a sentence that reads like this:

> Children need to learn to accept the consequences of **to** their actions.

Is the preposition "to" in above sentence needed? Is it correct to have it?

Comment: Are you by any chance looking at [this test](http://www.s-oman.net/avb/archive/index.php/t-475172.html), there or elsewhere? You should be warned that it contains many errors and unidiomatic expressions.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly same test that I'm doing, although mine is from a Cambridge book. It's the first time that I see there are errors from an authoritative publisher. Thanks for your warning, I'll be more careful about it. Here is a really good place to confirm it when I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It's superfluous. Unnecessary. Not only that, it's wrong and ungrammatical to use both *of* and *to* in the sentence. You should only use one or the other.

Comment: Is it wrong to include it?

Comment: Yes, because it does not add anything in terms of meaning. It's just surplus to requirements.

Comment: Note that "to" would be valid in constructions such as *You must accept that there are [consequences to your actions*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22consequences+to+your+actions%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but you'd have to settle for one preposition or the other. It's not just "superfluous" to use both - it's totally ungrammatical.

Comment: I'd say worse than superfluous: it's wrong. It's not optional, it shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: Tristan, would you mind editing your answer to add that the construction isn't simply superfluous, but wrong and ungrammatical? Failing that, @FumbleFingers, I'd post a separate answer with that example and explanation if I were you; though the comment here explains what's lacking in the answer, I'm afraid not everyone in the future will read them (and I'm not entirely comfortable that the only answer to the question refers to a completely incorrect construction as simply "superfluous"). Thoughts, everyone?

Comment: @WendiKidd: I'm inclined to agree. I neither up- nor down-voted this answer. As of now, my comment has 6 votes, but this answer itself only 3. I'll post an answer making clear that "superfluous" and "unnecessary" are *not* suitable characterisations. Come to that, "No" is a rather simplistic answer when the reality it "Either, but not both. Oh - and one of the two is 10 times more common than the other".

Answer (score 4):

In most such contexts, native speakers [overwhelmingly use **of**...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consequences%20of%20his%20actions,consequences%20to%20his%20actions&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

...but it's worth noting that the red line on the bottom isn't completely flat - [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22consequences%20to%20your%20actions%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are a couple of thousand written instances of forms such as *You must accept that there are [consequences to your actions.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22consequences%20to%20your%20actions%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)*

That's to say, **of** is standard and very much preferred, but **to** is equally grammatical (though far less common). OP's use of both together is not at all grammatical/acceptable to native speakers.